# Excel: SMALL(), IF() and ROW() to look up row numbers of values using multiple criteria - AND() not working

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a reference spreadsheet called `Purchases` that looks similar to this:

```
        A           B              C              D
1       Ord_ID      Supplier       PO_Date        Receipt_Quantity
2       PO101       Aa             11/1/2017      5
3       PO102       Bb             12/1/2017      12
4       PO103       Cc             12/15/2017     100
5       PO104       Bb             1/15/2018      8
6       PO105       Dd             2/1/2018       30
7       PO106       Bb             3/1/2018       15
8       PO107       Bb             4/1/2018       10
...
```

I have a separate sheet called `Supplier Bb Data` that is supposed to return the row numbers of `Purchases` data for Supplier Bb. The formula looks like this, and is in cells `A10`, `A11`, `A12`, etc.:

```
=SMALL(IF('Purchases'!$B:$B=$A$1, ROW('Purchases'!$B:$B)), ROW(1:1))
=SMALL(IF('Purchases'!$B:$B=$A$1, ROW('Purchases'!$B:$B)), ROW(2:2))
=SMALL(IF('Purchases'!$B:$B=$A$1, ROW('Purchases'!$B:$B)), ROW(3:3))
...
```

`A1` in `Supplier Bb Data` contains the the value to look up, "Bb".

This formula works; it correctlt returns row numbers from `Purchases` that include POs for Supplier Bb. (`3`, `5`, `7`, `8`, etc.)

However, I want to be able to return more specific data: rows where `Supplier = Bb` AND `PO_Date >= 1/1/2018`, AND `PO_Date <= 3/1/2018`. Consequently, returning `5` and `7`.

It seemed like it would be simple; I tried this (assuming `1/1/2018` and `3/1/2018` are in cells `A2` and `A3`, respectively):

```
=SMALL(IF(AND('Purchases'!$B:$B=$A$1, 'Purchases'!$C$C>=$A$2, 'Purchases!$C$C<=$A$3), 
ROW('Purchases'!$B:$B)), ROW(1:1))
```

When I try this, excel simply returns `0` for the first row, and errors for all following rows.

Does `AND()` simply not work within an `IF()` statement? What else can I try to get this to work?

I always press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` for these cells, because they are array formulas, so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AND function performs cyclic (*array style*) calculation by itself. Subsequently, AND or OR functions do not play well with others in an array style (CSE) formula. Stack the conditions in a nested IF or use AGGREGATE for your purposes.

```
'array style with CSE
=SMALL(IF(Purchases!$B:$B=$A$1, IF(Purchases!$C:$C>=$A$2, IF(Purchases!$C:$C<=$A$3, ROW($B:$B)))), ROW(1:1))

'standard style without CSE
=AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(B:B)/((Purchases!B:B=A$1)*(Purchases!C:C>=A$2)*(Purchases!C:C<=A$3)), ROW(1:1))
```

- You were missing a `:` in `'Purchases'!$C$C`.
- All worksheets in a workbook have the same number of rows. `ROW(B:B)` can be used in place of `ROW('Purchases'!$B:$B))`.
- The `ROW(1:1)` indicates that you are dragging down for successive *k* parameters. There is no need to lock the columns as absolute.
- Array formulas or functions with cyclic calculation perform much more efficiently if you don't use full column references. Consider the following:

  ```
  =AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($1:$999)/((Purchases!B$1:B$999=A$1)*(Purchases!C$1:C$999>=A$2)*(Purchases!C$1:C$999<=A$3)), ROW(1:1))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can combine your SMALL+IF with SUMPRODUCT function (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(IF((Purchases!$B$1:$B$8=$A$1)*(Purchases!$C$1:$C$8>=$A$2)*(Purchases!$C$1:$C$8<=$A$3)=0,"",(ROW(Purchases!$B$1:$B$8))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```